# balls-and-urns in PyMC

Tags: pymc

In trying to wrap my head around Bayesian statistics and PyMC I've been trying to program up a balls-and-urns example. Sadly, I'm failing miserably.

Assume that I'm drawing balls from an urn and know that the composition of the urn is either 80 black/20 red balls or 20 black/80 red balls. I have a uniform prior over the probability that I'm drawing from the first urn and now get to draw repeatedly and with replacement from the urn to figure it out. I wrote this up as a PyMC model, like so:

```
import pymc as pymc
import numpy as np

# we're actually drawing from the first urn
balls = np.random.binomial(1,0.8,size=1000)

black_probs = [0.8,0.2]

urn_0_prob = pymc.Uniform('urn_0_prob',lower=0,upper=1)
assignment = pymc.Categorical("assignment", p=[urn_0_prob,1-urn_0_prob])

@pymc.deterministic
def black_prob(assignment=assignment):
    return black_probs[assignment]

observations = pymc.Bernoulli("observations", p=black_prob, value=balls, observed=True)

model = pymc.Model([urn_0_prob,assignment,black_prob,observations])
```

This looks sensible to me but I'm obviously doing something wrong because this doesn't work:

```
mcmc = pymc.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(10000,0)

mcmc.stats()

{'assignment': {'95% HPD interval': array([ 0.,  0.]),
  'mc error': 0.0,
  'mean': 0.0,
  'n': 10000,
  'quantiles': {2.5: 0.0, 25: 0.0, 50: 0.0, 75: 0.0, 97.5: 0.0},
  'standard deviation': 0.0},
 'black_prob': {'95% HPD interval': array([ 0.8,  0.8]),
  'mc error': 1.1102230246251566e-17,
  'mean': 0.80000000000000016,
  'n': 10000,
  'quantiles': {2.5: 0.80000000000000004,
   25: 0.80000000000000004,
   50: 0.80000000000000004,
   75: 0.80000000000000004,
   97.5: 0.80000000000000004},
  'standard deviation': 1.1102230246251565e-16},
 'urn_0_prob': {'95% HPD interval': array([ 0.2186279 ,  0.99966969]),
  'mc error': 0.0062019203981026425,
  'mean': 0.6646822946585289,
  'n': 10000,
  'quantiles': {2.5: 0.15802813648110903,
   25: 0.48846888794346444,
   50: 0.70758248557324599,
   75: 0.87243103830208035,
   97.5: 0.98900646106466972},
  'standard deviation': 0.24170398816390645}}
```

Why is the assignment always 0 when the probability that governs the assignment varies pretty widely in [0,1]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you have observed all 1000 draws from a single urn.  This gives overwhelming probability that the assignment=0.  But since you have observed only one assignment, you can't determine the value of urn_0_prob.  That's like trying to estimate the bias of a coin from observing a single flip.